# Incorrect Syntax in a Pivot

Tags: sql, pivot

I have been tasked with creating an sql script based on an OrdinalPosition, as far as I can tell my code should be working, but there is apparently an "incorrect syntax" error near the very last "ViewData.SONumber" which I am both unable to solve and unable to identify. Can someone take a look and see if there is something my brain just isn't processing?

```
FROM    tblReps RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblServiceOrders RIGHT OUTER JOIN     dbo.tblCustomFieldDefinitions LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    (SELECT SONumber, [1] AS [ShippingCompany], [2] AS [Consignment_Number]
                    FROM        (SELECT     tvw_CustomSOFieldData.SONumber, tvw_CustomSOFieldData.CustomFieldValue, tvw_CustomSOFieldData.OrdinalPosition
                                FROM    tvw_CustomSOFieldData)
                                PivotData PIVOT(max(CustomFieldValue) FOR OrdinalPosition IN ([1], [2])) AS CustomFieldsPivot)
                                AS ViewData ON tblServiceOrders.SONumber = ViewData.SONumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears you are missing several things with your syntax.  You are missing the `ON` syntax on several of your `JOIN`s:

```
FROM    tblReps 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblServiceOrders 
  ON -- missing JOIN
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblCustomFieldDefinitions 
  ON -- missing JOIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT SONumber, 
    [1] AS [ShippingCompany], 
    [2] AS [Consignment_Number]
  FROM        
  (
    SELECT tvw_CustomSOFieldData.SONumber, 
      tvw_CustomSOFieldData.CustomFieldValue, 
      tvw_CustomSOFieldData.OrdinalPosition
    FROM    tvw_CustomSOFieldData
  ) PivotData 
  PIVOT
  (
    max(CustomFieldValue) 
    FOR OrdinalPosition IN ([1], [2])
  ) CustomFieldsPivot
) ViewData 
  ON tblServiceOrders.SONumber = ViewData.SONumber
```

Comment: But of course! Thank you kind sir, such a simple and idiotic mistake

Comment: Perhaps the syntax encourages it.